# Проверка на наличие значений в PySimpleGUI InputText/полях ввода значения (if values['-YourName-']!=None)

Tags: python, pysimplegui

у меня такой код

```
 [sg.Text('Телефон'), sg.InputText(size=(20, 3), key='-PhonNumReg-', )],
            [sg.Text('Пароль'), sg.InputText(size=(20, 3), key='-Password1Reg-')],
            [sg.Text('Повторите пароль'), sg.InputText(size=(20, 3), key='-Password2Reg-')],
            [sg.Text('Имя'), sg.InputText(size=(20, 3), key='-Name1Reg-')],
            [sg.Text('Фамилия'), sg.InputText(size=(20, 3), key='-Name2Reg-')],
            [sg.Submit("Далее")]]
```

я хочу проверить `values['-PhonNumReg-']` на наличия введеного текста, проверяю так(не работает)
`if values['-PhonNumReg-']!=None` и так  `if values['-PhonNumReg-']!=''`

Comment: Добавьте в текст вопроса еще код проверки пожалуйста.